# Reusable bcrypt function, returning data from function issue

Tags: javascript, bcrypt, modularity

I have this hashing function where I would like to get back all hashes that are made using bcryptjs. When I `console.log(encrypt(password))` it returns `undefined`. I've attempted to do a `Promise.all` but I'm not very good with promises. Considering the fact it returns undefined my guess would be that it is the way the function is structured.

**function**

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

module.exports = function encrypt(password) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, async (err, salt) => {
      const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
      const details = {
        password: encryptedPassword,
      };
      return details;
    });
};
```

Let me know if you need anything else from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using async and await like this, for encrypted password

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");        
module.exports = async function encryptPassword(password) { 
    return await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
};
```